# Howto put elements over two bootstrap containers and make it responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m searching the best way to put a div element over two twitter bootstrap containers. The problem comes when the window is resized.

[image]

I´m using position: absolute; but I´m sure there is a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a better way.

This is how I would do it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.col1 {
  background-color: blue; 
    height: 50vh;}
.col2 {
  background-color: green; 
  height: 50vh;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  top: 25%;
  right: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/od0peVvEXc

You may want to use a media query to keep the sizes more consistent on different size screens.